# error in Converting to numeric python

Tags: pandas, reshape, data-cleaning

I have a column in a dataframe that has some numbers and text

```
2009-07-06 05:06:09     Comm Fail
2009-07-06 05:06:29      48,15125
2009-07-06 07:54:58      48,03313
2009-07-06 10:27:29      48,16438
2009-07-07 01:02:19      48,15125
2009-07-07 03:18:28      48,15125
2009-07-07 03:18:38  Scan Timeout
2009-07-07 03:20:19       48,1425
2009-07-07 08:57:49       48,1775
2009-07-07 11:15:38      48,16875
2009-07-08 05:04:59      48,15125
2009-07-08 08:34:39     Comm Fail


 dtype: object
```

but when I convert to np.float , I use :

```
Frequency['Frequency']=pd.to_numeric(Frequency['Frequency'], errors='coerce')
```

But I got as results :

```
2009-07-06 05:06:29   NaN
2009-07-06 07:54:58   NaN
2009-07-06 10:27:29   NaN
2009-07-07 01:02:19   NaN
2009-07-07 03:18:28   NaN
2009-07-07 03:18:38   NaN
2009-07-07 03:20:19   NaN
2009-07-07 08:57:49   NaN
2009-07-07 11:15:38   NaN
2009-07-08 05:04:59   NaN
2009-07-08 08:34:39   NaN
2009-07-08 09:09:08   NaN
```

How Can I please solve this issue ..?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the commas. Are those decimal points?

```
df['Frequency'] = (
    pd.to_numeric(df['Frequency'].str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce'))
```

If they're not meant to be decimal points, just remove them (use `.str.replace(',', '')` instead).

Comment: @HarvIpan happens. :) I have to go to work in a bit so you'll have more chances soon...